# how vscode recognize type of js module

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

i am new to javascript and typescript,and i install mysql module using`npm install mysql`

and i found that the **intellisense** of vscode can automatically recognize the type even when i'm using javascript

just like this

[image]

and the module source file doesn't contain any **.ts** file,i wonder how it work.

Comment: Most likely the mysql module has documented it's methods using [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/). VSCode has built in support for this documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code downloads TS typings in the background. It checks package.json or imports to decide which typings to get. The typing for mysql:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8f158d2d4c8459463e5e0a27cc298041483c5e22/types/mysql/index.d.ts

For more info follow the link bellow:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript

Comment: You can mark this as an answer, if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql package is written in pure JS, however it includes documentation. This documentation is standardized as [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/). VSCode has built in support for reading this documentation and displaying it to the user. (Note: it does not support all JSDoc tags)

Example from `mysql/index.js`. ([source](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/index.js))

```
/**
 * Create a new Connection instance.
 * @param {object|string} config Configuration or connection string for new MySQL connection
 * @return {Connection} A new MySQL connection
 * @public
 */
exports.createConnection = function createConnection(config) {
  var Connection       = loadClass('Connection');
  var ConnectionConfig = loadClass('ConnectionConfig');

  return new Connection({config: new ConnectionConfig(config)});
};
```

The `@param` tag specifies what types `config` can receive. `{object|string}` means it can either be an object or a string.

Comment: but when i click '''go to definition''' option of this function,it jump to a folder in 
'C:/users/xxx/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/3.7/node_modules/@types//mysql/index.d.ts'

Comment: Probably Dauren Akilbekov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59999889/7448536) also applies.